# Rails ActiveRecord fetch records with appropriate data types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using Ruby, I want data in array of hash format.

I have tried out ActiveRecord's select_al method. But it returns all the data in string format, does not matter what type is its type in data base. All numbers are also returned in string format.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
MyModel.all.map &:attributes
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
MyModel.find(:all).collect {|x| x.attributes}
```